# C# Hash Code for triangle class

Tags: c#, hashcode

I have a custom class to handle some triangle calculations that I am doing. For the most part I am happy with it, however, there is one aspect that I don't really trust. That is my implementation of HashCode.

Some quick information about my triangle- it has 3 Vector2 structs that represent points of two floats. This is an inbuilt class with the Unity engine but the simple version of it is that it is a struct with two floats and a couple math functions.

```
public class Triangle2D {
    public Vector2 point1;
    public Vector2 point2;
    public Vector2 point3;

    //... Some other methods that don't matter

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        var hashCode = -305700999;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + (EqualityComparer<Vector2>.Default.GetHashCode (point1)
            + EqualityComparer<Vector2>.Default.GetHashCode (point2)
            + EqualityComparer<Vector2>.Default.GetHashCode (point3));
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

The specific thing about this class that is special is that, it shouldn't matter what order points 1, 2 and 3 are in. If the points are shared, then the Triangle2D objects are the same. My equals function reflects that, but I worry that my hashCode function is not specific enough. Due to the additive nature of things, I suspect there could be a lot of collisions.

Is there some way that I could make the hashCode function have less collisions? Is it good enough as it is?

I use this object in a lot of hashSets to prevent duplicate triangles from getting listed.

Comment: There are like one million answers on [SO] about calculating the hash-code.

Comment: I think you actually consider your code broken, because it has too many hash collisions and you are asking how to make the function more robust. I believe it is actually off-topic for CodeReview.

Comment: [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/463206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hash code

> it shouldn't matter what order points 1, 2 and 3 are in

There is a way to ensure that: Sorting. Sort your points locally within your hashcode method, first by their x value, then by their y value.

---

The algorithm for the hashcode could be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/263416#263416), as also commented above by radarbob. I will leave it for you to adapt it to your own class.

### General

Your class has public fields. It is better to make these private and grant public access to them (if needed) via properties. In this case, for something like a triangle, making it a struct instead of a class might be also suitable.

---

The following piece of code does not make much sense:

```
var hashCode = -305700999;
hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + [...]
```

I already added the link to a good implementation of the hash code method above, so I won't go into detail about the algorithm. But what you are doing in the above two lines before the addition is just calculating what could simply be a constant. The compiler will probably even precompute the `-305700999 * -1521134295` part. Multiplying the hash code with a prime number (like 23 or 31) should happen before every addition of another value.

Comment: +1 Now that you mention public fields, one should be *very* careful when deriving a hash code from mutable fields (or properties). It can cause subtle problems such as dictionary or hash set lookups failing.

Comment: Thanks for that public fields thing... I'm just being lazy here. I never actually change those values, but nothing in my code prevents it.

Comment: Originally I had this as a struct, but I changed it to a class at some point. I can't remember why, but at the time I thought that I had a good reason. I'll check back over my code and see if I was just making dumb.

Comment: Another question, as I am still fairly new to C# (Just made the jump over from Java). With my 3 sorted points, since I only ever get these points, would it be better to overload a getter, have an accessor function or even override [] for index access on the points?

Comment: @S.Buda You could add a property that gives you an `IEnumerable` so that the order doesn't matter. Then the caller can iterate over the points, for example to draw them on a canvas.

Answer (score -3):

Overall this looks good, but I have one question, why don't you write this as

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    var hashCode = -305700999 * -1521134295;
    hashCode += (EqualityComparer<Vector2>.Default.GetHashCode (point1)
        + EqualityComparer<Vector2>.Default.GetHashCode (point2)
        + EqualityComparer<Vector2>.Default.GetHashCode (point3));
    return hashCode;
}
```

This should be the same, and it seems cleaner. Also, what are those random constants?

Comment: This isn't really an improvement as it repeats the same mistakes as OP's code.

Comment: Also, answers shouldn't be questions. Asking for further information should be done in comments on the question.